# Rewrite Haskell expression in prefix notation

Tags: haskell

I would like to implement a program that would take any Haskell expression and rewrite it using prefix notation.

I was hoping that `GHC` itself would dump some helpful information (like added parentheses after parsing), but unfortunately this does not seem to be the case.

```
$ ghc Example.hs -fforce-recomp -ddump-tc
[1 of 1] Compiling Example          ( Example.hs, Example.o )
TYPE SIGNATURES
  f :: Maybe ()
TYPE CONSTRUCTORS
COERCION AXIOMS
Dependent modules: []
Dependent packages: [base-4.8.1.0, ghc-prim-0.4.0.0,
                     integer-gmp-1.0.0.0]

==================== Typechecker ====================
AbsBinds [] []
  {Exports: [f <= f_alA
               <>]
   Exported types: f :: Maybe ()
                   [LclId, Str=DmdType]
   Binds: f_alA = ($) const (GHC.Base.Just) "Foo" GHC.Tuple.()}
```

What existing API would be best suited for this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What existing API would be best suited for this task?

With Template Haskell and a package `th-desugar` to desugar Template Haskell. The idea is simple: wrap the expression in quasi-quote, desugar it as template haskell, then render it to haskell code again.

I'm reusing the code for anothe answer here so it may be a little messy:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import           Control.Monad
import           Generics.Deriving.Monoid
import           GHC.Generics
import           Language.Haskell.TH.Desugar

data T = MkT {str :: String, str' :: String}
  deriving (Generic, Show)

main = $([| print $ MkT "a" "b" `mappend` MkT "c" "d" |] >>= dsExp >>= return . expToTH)

instance Monoid T where
  mempty = memptydefault
  mappend = mappenddefault
```

By `-ddump-splices` ghc will dump a `*.dump-splices` file showing what template haskell had done to the source code:

```
app\Main.hs:12:10-87: Splicing expression
    [| print $ MkT "a" "b" `mappend` MkT "c" "d" |] >>= dsExp
    >>= return . expToTH
  ======>
    ($) print (mappend (MkT "a" "b") (MkT "c" "d"))
```